# I'm getting an xpath error when navigating to an element in the soap message

Tags: c#, xpath, soap

**Programming Langauge** - c#.

Below mentioned error is showing.

```
Unhandled Exception: System.Xml.XPath.XPathException: Namespace Manager or XsltC
ontext needed. This query has a prefix, variable, or user-defined function.
```

This is the code that I wrote to return the inner text.

```
 XmlDocument xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
 xmldoc.Load(@"C:\test\myfile.xml");
 var nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(xmldoc.NameTable);
 nsmgr.AddNamespace("env", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/");
 nsmgr.AddNamespace("ns1", "http://sse/ECOM:1.0:schema:messages");
 nsmgr.AddNamespace("wsa", "http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing");
 XmlNode node = xmldoc.SelectsingleNode("/*/env:Body/env:response/env:customerAccountsGrp[1]/env:customerAccountID"); 
 Console.WriteLine(xmldoc.SelectSingleNode("/*/env:Body/env:response/env:customerAccountsGrp[1]/env:customerAccountID").InnerText);
```

This is the soap message

```
<env:Envelope
xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
<env:Header>
<wsa:MessageID>urn:5C4DCC70E6F411E69F7EF5AAD683B4B3</wsa:MessageID>
<wsa:ReplyTo>
<wsa:Address>http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous</wsa:Address>
</wsa:ReplyTo><wsa:FaultTo> <wsa:Address>http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous</wsa:Address>
</wsa:FaultTo>
</env:Header>
<env:Body>
<response 
xmlns:ns0="urn:sse:ECOM:1.0:schema:messages"
xmlns="urn:sse:ECOM:1.0:schema:messages">
 <ns0:customerAccountsGrp>
<ns0:customerAccountID>1212121212</ns0:customerAccountID>
<ns0:customerAccountStatus>AC</ns0:customerAccountStatus>
<ns0:serviceType>AB</ns0:serviceType>
<ns0:brandCode>XXX </ns0:brandCode>
<ns0:affinityType> </ns0:affinityType>
<ns0:paymentType>VV</ns0:paymentType>
</ns0:customerAccountsGrp><ns0:customerAccountsGrp>
<ns0:customerAccountID>4545454545445</ns0:customerAccountID>
<ns0:customerAccountStatus>BC</ns0:customerAccountStatus>
<ns0:serviceType>FH</ns0:serviceType>
<ns0:brandCode>SE</ns0:brandCode>
<ns0:affinityType></ns0:affinityType>
<ns0:paymentType>NM</ns0:paymentType>
</ns0:customerAccountsGrp>
```

Can anyone help me on this issue?
Best Regards.

Comment: You haven't declared the namespaces `xmlns:ns0="urn:sse:ECOM:1.0:schema:messages"
xmlns="urn:sse:ECOM:1.0:schema:messages">` You've partially converted them to URIs. They should appear exactly as they are in the SOAP envelope

Comment: I have done that now but still getting the same error......        nsmgr.AddNamespace("env",     http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/");
                nsmgr.AddNamespace("ns0", "xmlns:ns0=urn:sse:ECOM:1.0:schema:messages");
                nsmgr.AddNamespace("ns1", "xmlns = urn:sse:ECOM:1.0:schema:messages");
                nsmgr.AddNamespace("wsa", "http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing");
            XmlNode node = xmldoc.SelectSingleNode("/env:Envelope/env:Body/env:response/ns0:customerAccountsGrp[1]/ns0:customerAccountID");

Comment: Thanks got it now...working

Comment: nsmgr.AddNamespace("ns0", "urn:sse:ECOM:1.0:schema:messages");
            nsmgr.AddNamespace("ns1", urn:sse:ECOM:1.0:schema:messages");